# When I run the sportsipy.nba.teams.Teams function I am getting notified that The requested page returned a valid response, but no data could be found

Tags: python

The code that I am running (straight from [sportsipy documentation](https://sportsreference.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)):

```
from sportsipy.nba.teams import Teams

teams = Teams()
for team in teams:
    print(team.name, team.abbreviation)
```

Returns the following:

The requested page returned a valid response, but no data could be found. Has the season begun, and is the data available on [www.sports-reference.com](http://www.sports-reference.com)?

Does anyone have any tips on moving forward with getting this information from the API?

Comment: maybe web page changed structure and/or it has new system to detect bots/scripts/spamers/hacker - and it may need to change code in module - so it may need to wait for newer version.

Answer (score 0):

That package api is old/outdated. The table it's trying to parse now has a different id attribute.

Few things you can do:

1. Go in and edit/patch the code manually to get the correct data.
2. Raise the issue on the github and wait for the fix and update.

Personally, the patch/fix is a quick easy one, so just do that (but there could be potentially other tables you may need to look into).

Open up the `nba_utils.py`:

change lines 85 and 86:

From:

```
teams_list = utils._get_stats_table(doc, 'div#all_team-stats-base')
opp_teams_list = utils._get_stats_table(doc, 'div#all_opponent-stats-base')
```

To:

```
teams_list = utils._get_stats_table(doc, '#totals-team')
opp_teams_list = utils._get_stats_table(doc, '#totals-opponent')
```

This will solve the current error, however, I don't know what other classes and functions may also need to be patched. There's a chance since this table slighltly changed, other may have as well.

**Output:**

```
Charlotte Hornets CHO
Milwaukee Bucks MIL
Utah Jazz UTA
Sacramento Kings SAC
Memphis Grizzlies MEM
Los Angeles Lakers LAL
Miami Heat MIA
Indiana Pacers IND
Houston Rockets HOU
Phoenix Suns PHO
Atlanta Hawks ATL
Minnesota Timberwolves MIN
San Antonio Spurs SAS
Boston Celtics BOS
Cleveland Cavaliers CLE
Golden State Warriors GSW
Washington Wizards WAS
Portland Trail Blazers POR
Los Angeles Clippers LAC
New Orleans Pelicans NOP
Dallas Mavericks DAL
Brooklyn Nets BRK
New York Knicks NYK
Orlando Magic ORL
Philadelphia 76ers PHI
Chicago Bulls CHI
Denver Nuggets DEN
Toronto Raptors TOR
Oklahoma City Thunder OKC
Detroit Pistons DET
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just not use the api and get the data yourself. If you don't need the abbreviations, it's pretty straight forward with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
    
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022.html'

teams = list(pd.read_html(url)[4].dropna(subset=['Rk'])['Team'])
for team in teams:
    print(team)
```

If you do need the abbreviations, then it's a little more tricky, but can be achieved using BeautifulSoup to pull it out of the team href:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'per_game-team'})
rows = table.find_all('td', {'data-stat':'team'})

teams = {}
for row in rows:
    if row.find('a'):
        name = row.find('a').text
        abbreviation = row.find('a')['href'].split('/')[-2]
        
        teams.update({name:abbreviation})
    

for team in teams.items():
    print(team[0], team[1])
```