# sportsipy.nba.teams.Teams error The requested page returned a valid response, but no data could be found

Tags: python, pandas, web, web-scraping

have already referred to the thread, but even that doesn't seem to work.
[When I run the sportsipy.nba.teams.Teams function I am getting notified that The requested page returned a valid response, but no data could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519889/when-i-run-the-sportsipy-nba-teams-teams-function-i-am-getting-notified-that-the)

i guess the div name has changed again, can anyone please update the div names.

code-
'''

```
from sportsipy.nba.teams import Teams
year='2018'
teams = Teams(year)
playeridlist = []
nba_player_filename = f'nbaplayer-{year}.list'
for team in teams:
    print('Getting players for team: ' + team.name)

    for player in team.roster.players:
       
       playeridlist.append(player.name)
       playeridlist.append("\n")
       
with open(nba_player_filename, 'w+') as player_file:
    player_file.writelines(playeridlist)
```

'''''

Comment: Your question would be better received if you showed good faith effort to solve the problem on your own. Please [edit] your question to show your work and provide a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried. Then explain where you ran into problems, what results are unexpected, and what errors you get.

Comment: hi, added the code, do take a look